# How to generate a savings simulation with Python and Polars which earns interest and carries a closing balance over each month

Tags: python, simulation, python-polars, accounting

I am trying to generate simulations of a savings plan (e.g., bank savings or retirement) which allows an opening balance each month to earn some variable interest and might have deposits (or withdrawals), and tally this for a closing balance each month and carries this closing amount over to the opening balance next month.
Imagine that your neighbor's kid is mowing lawns and using his allowance to save money to buy a gaming console in six months, and his uncle has agreed to match some of his earnings each month based on how much he has accrued that month.
(I asked a more simple version of this question previously, but failed to include the concept of accruing interest, which makes the concept of resolving the closing balance each month necessary so as to carry that amount forward to the following month so as to earn interest on the total. Previous question with simple addition of profit and loss which can use a tally of cumulative_eval() [at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75771032/generate-a-running-tally-with-polars-where-the-closing-balance-one-month-becomes/75771581#75771581).)

Let us start with knowing the following:

1. The kid starts with $500.
2. He earns additional money for mowing lawns, but also has some overhead (e.g., fuel, maintenance) so the amount of income each month can vary widely.
3. His uncle will pay him some interest (depending on moodiness) for how much he saved during the month.
4. He wonders if he will have saved enough at the end of a period of time.

I tried to use various `.with_columns()` expressions, but could not have this carry the `'closing_balance'` forward month-after-month. Someone showed me an example with `.cumulative_eval()` which worked well for the simple case of adding (or subtracting) amounts, but does not handle the case when interest is earned based on the opening balance.
So the only way that I currently know to resolve this (where the monthly closing balance becomes the opening balance for the following month) is to use an external loop; unfortunately, this greatly defeats the optimizations available via Polars.
Here is the code for a working example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
import polars as pl
import datetime as dt
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from random import normalvariate

starting_balance = 500.00  # how much money they start with (i.e., this month's closing balance)
milestone = 6              # how many months to save
income_average = 700.00    # how much they earn from mowing yards on an average month
income_std = 300.00        # a standard deviation of their mowing income
interest_average = 0.10    # how much his uncle will contribute each month on average, e.g. 10%
interest_std = 0.10        # the uncle is flaky and his contribution varies so much that he might ask for some money back (loss)

start_date = dt.date.today().replace(day=1)  # first day of this month
calendar_date = pl.date_range(start_date, start_date + relativedelta(months=milestone), '1mo')
zeroes = [0.0 for _ in range(milestone + 1)]

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        'date': pl.date_range(low=start_date, high=(start_date + relativedelta(months=milestone)), interval="1mo"),
        'opening_balance': zeroes,
        'interest': zeroes,  # or [normalvariate(interest_average, interest_std) for _ in zeroes]
        'income': zeroes,  # or [normalvariate(income_average, income_std) for _ in zeroes]
        'closing_balance': zeroes,
    }
)
print(df, f"\n initialized dataframe")
```

```
┌────────────┬─────────────────┬──────────┬────────┬─────────────────┐
│ date       ┆ opening_balance ┆ interest ┆ income ┆ closing_balance │
│ ---        ┆ ---             ┆ ---      ┆ ---    ┆ ---             │
│ date       ┆ f64             ┆ f64      ┆ f64    ┆ f64             │
╞════════════╪═════════════════╪══════════╪════════╪═════════════════╡
│ 2023-03-01 ┆ 0.0             ┆ 0.0      ┆ 0.0    ┆ 0.0             │
│ 2023-04-01 ┆ 0.0             ┆ 0.0      ┆ 0.0    ┆ 0.0             │
│ 2023-05-01 ┆ 0.0             ┆ 0.0      ┆ 0.0    ┆ 0.0             │
│ 2023-06-01 ┆ 0.0             ┆ 0.0      ┆ 0.0    ┆ 0.0             │
│ 2023-07-01 ┆ 0.0             ┆ 0.0      ┆ 0.0    ┆ 0.0             │
│ 2023-08-01 ┆ 0.0             ┆ 0.0      ┆ 0.0    ┆ 0.0             │
│ 2023-09-01 ┆ 0.0             ┆ 0.0      ┆ 0.0    ┆ 0.0             │
└────────────┴─────────────────┴──────────┴────────┴─────────────────┘ 
 initialized dataframe
```

```
current_tally = starting_balance
for m in range(len(calendar_date)):
    if m == 0:
        df[m, 'opening_balance'] = 0.0
        df[m, 'interest'] = 0.0
        df[m, 'income'] = 0.0
    else:
        df[m, 'opening_balance'] = current_tally
        interest = normalvariate(interest_average, interest_std)
        income = round(normalvariate(income_average, income_std), 2)
        current_tally *= (1 + interest)
        current_tally = round(current_tally + income, 2)
        df[m, 'interest'] = interest
        df[m, 'income'] = income
    df[m, 'closing_balance'] = round(current_tally, 2)
print(df, f"\n slow population of dataframe with a running tally")
```

```
┌────────────┬─────────────────┬──────────┬─────────┬─────────────────┐
│ date       ┆ opening_balance ┆ interest ┆ income  ┆ closing_balance │
│ ---        ┆ ---             ┆ ---      ┆ ---     ┆ ---             │
│ date       ┆ f64             ┆ f64      ┆ f64     ┆ f64             │
╞════════════╪═════════════════╪══════════╪═════════╪═════════════════╡
│ 2023-03-01 ┆ 0.0             ┆ 0.0      ┆ 0.0     ┆ 500.0           │
│ 2023-04-01 ┆ 500.0           ┆ 0.311301 ┆ 767.38  ┆ 1423.03         │
│ 2023-05-01 ┆ 1423.03         ┆ 0.213937 ┆ 468.1   ┆ 2195.57         │
│ 2023-06-01 ┆ 2195.57         ┆ 0.073306 ┆ 1269.07 ┆ 3625.59         │
│ 2023-07-01 ┆ 3625.59         ┆ 0.118544 ┆ 1001.4  ┆ 5056.78         │
│ 2023-08-01 ┆ 5056.78         ┆ 0.175585 ┆ 344.57  ┆ 6289.25         │
│ 2023-09-01 ┆ 6289.25         ┆ 0.28428  ┆ 1139.38 ┆ 9216.54         │
└────────────┴─────────────────┴──────────┴─────────┴─────────────────┘ 
 slow population of dataframe with a running tally
```

I have spent many hours trying to learn what the optimized way to do this might be (via the Polars docs and any examples I could locate on the web), but still have not managed to grok the best way to do this. Any help and direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

With inspiration from [this polars issue](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/9175), you can use some numba ufuncs.

```
import polars as pl
from polars import col
from numba import jit, guvectorize, int64, float64

@guvectorize([(float64[:], float64[:], float64[:])], '(n),(n)->(n)', target='parallel')
def tally_func(x, y, res):
    for i in range(x.shape[0]):
        if i == 0:
            res[i] = 0
        else:
            res[i] = res[i-1] * (1+x[i]) + y[i]
            
def series_to_numba(x):
    a, b = map(lambda x: x.to_numpy(), x.to_frame().unnest("interest").get_columns())
    return pl.Series(values=tally_func(a, b))

# %%timeit
df.select(pl.struct('interest', 'income').map_batches(series_to_numba).alias('closing_balance'))

# other slower alternative
# %%timeit
df.select(tally_func(col('interest'), col('income')).alias('closing_balance'))
```

Comment: Windows expression don't seem to work with over with numbat ufuncs. I'm not sure how to solve that.

Comment: "Note that, in Rust, the type of the argument to over() must be a collection, so even when you're only using one column, you must provide it in an array." Over with an array works.